# raphael js Pan functionality using raphael-pan-zoom

Tags: javascript, zooming, raphael, pan

I found a plugin called raphael-pan-zoom that I use to zoom-in and zoom-out my raphaeljs elements in my paper, the zoom worked perfectly, but when I wanted to move the paper to the left, right, top or down I didn't success.
I found in the "raphael.pan-zoom.js" the pan function :

```
pan: function (deltaX, deltaY) {
    },
```

I don't know what is deltaX and deltaY and how to calculate them, can you help me please.
in this jsfiddle you can find an example : http://jsfiddle.net/xperali/g6Xav/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

version 0.2.1 now has implemented the pan function, the deltaX and deltaY are the number of points in X and Y you want to move the paper.

```
panZoom.pan(0, -10);
```

I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g6Xav/8/

Let me now if you have any problems

Comment: Thank's Escobar5, but I tested the updated jsfiddle in chrome and firefox and that's not work

Comment: It's working for me in chrome and firefox, did you zoomed in before? the pan only works when the paper is zoomed in, because to move the viewbox the paper must be larger than the viewbox itself.